# Expo + NextJS "fs module not found" build error

Tags: node.js, next.js, build, expo, monorepo

Using a Solito (https://solito.dev/), I've built a monorepo for NextJS + Expo React Native cross-platform application where I've successfully deployed both web and iOS apps.

But, I accidentally wiped my local repository and had to pull it from Github. Since then, I have been reaching this build error on the Expo iOS that I cannot solve. What is strange is that the web app works PERFECTLY FINE. But the Expo app is printing a NextJS error.

While building Expo app on my local simulator, it successfully builds and downloads on to the simulated iPhone. But once it finishes building, it is prints this error. The "gzip" module inside Next node_modules is stating `require('fs')` and fs doesn't exist.

```
iOS Bundling failed 29865ms
The package at "../../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/gzip-size/index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.
Learn more
[Omniio] Unable to resolve module fs from
/Users/quantumuniverse/Documents/GitHub/karma-trade-platform/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/gzip-size/index.js:
fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
../../node_modules/next/node_modules
../../node_modules
../../node_modules
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhEFN.png)

Here is my package.json (inside Next folder):

```
{
  "name": "next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "slicemachine": "start-slicemachine",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006 ",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@expo/next-adapter": "5.0.2",
    "@happykit/flags": "^3.0.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.0.6",
    "@pdfme/generator": "^1.0.18",
    "@pdfme/ui": "^1.1.9",
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.7.1",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.6",
    "@prismicio/next": "^1.0.2",
    "@prismicio/react": "^2.5.2",
    "@prismicio/slice-simulator-react": "^0.2.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.2",
    "@react-native/assets-registry": "^0.72.0",
    "@segment/analytics-next": "^1.47.1",
    "@segment/analytics-node": "^0.0.1-beta.8",
    "@segment/snippet": "^4.15.3",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.43.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@twilio/conversations": "^2.3.0",
    "app": "*",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.4",
    "graphql-middleware": "^6.1.28",
    "inngest": "^2.0.1",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.7",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.11.1",
    "motion": "^10.15.5",
    "next": "^13.2.0",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-seo": "^5.15.0",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "pusher": "^5.1.1-beta",
    "pusher-js": "^7.5.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks-router-nextjs": "^6.43.0",
    "react-mailchimp-form": "^1.0.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.20",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "slice-machine-ui": "^0.5.2",
    "square": "^27.0.0",
    "taxjar": "^4.0.1",
    "type-graphql": "2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "^5.79.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0-placeholder-for-preset-env.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.18.6",
    "@prismicio/types": "^0.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.20",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^0.3.2",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "@types/raf": "^3.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.2",
    "customerio-expo-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "customerio-reactnative": "^2.3.3",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.76.1",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "slice-machine-ui": "^0.5.2",
    "storybook": "^7.1.0-alpha.3",
    "storybook-addon-next": "^1.8.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json (inside Expo folder):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/mulish": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-native-menu/menu": "^0.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@segment/analytics-react-native": "^2.15.0",
    "@segment/sovran-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.28.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-terminal-react-native": "^0.0.1-beta.12",
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "app": "*",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.1.0",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-cached-image": "^45.1.1",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.8",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.0.5",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "firebase": "^9.9.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-native": "^0.72.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^6.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.71.4",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/cli": "6.3.2",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^6.0.0",
    "metro": "0.76.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "metro-resolver": "0.76.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx expo start --dev-client -c --tunnel",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "AppTrackingTransparency",
    "BluetoothPeripheral",
    "Calendars",
    "Camera",
    "Contacts",
    "FaceID",
    "LocationAccuracy",
    "LocationAlways",
    "LocationWhenInUse",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Motion",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly",
    "Reminders",
    "Siri",
    "SpeechRecognition",
    "StoreKit"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "expo-app"
}
```

Here is my package.json (at root):

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "app",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@algolia/autocomplete-js": "^1.7.1",
    "@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic": "^1.7.1",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.1",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.3",
    "@as-integrations/next": "^1.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await": "^7.14.5",
    "@capsizecss/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.8.6",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.15.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/match-media": "^0.3.0",
    "@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
    "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@graphql-tools/stitch": "^8.6.12",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.8",
    "@knocklabs/client": "^0.8.8",
    "@knocklabs/node": "^0.4.23",
    "@knocklabs/react-notification-feed": "^0.8.3",
    "@magicbell/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@magicbell/magicbell-react": "^10.3.2",
    "@magicbell/react-headless": "^4.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.10",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.2",
    "@pinecone-database/pinecone": "^0.0.10",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.14.0",
    "@prismicio/client": "^6.7.1",
    "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.6",
    "@prismicio/react": "^2.5.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@shopify/hydrogen-react": "^2023.4.4",
    "@shopify/shopify-api": "^7.3.1",
    "@snooper/react-native-video-processing": "^1.22.8",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.32.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/micro-cors": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/shippo": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@xstate/react": "^3.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.13.1",
    "apollo-datasource-mongodb": "^0.5.4",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^3.11.1",
    "array-to-image": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator": "^1.0.16",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
    "blurhash": "^1.1.5",
    "bson": "^5.0.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cloudinary-build-url": "^0.2.4",
    "cross-undici-fetch": "^0.4.3",
    "csv": "^6.2.1",
    "dataloader": "^2.1.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.3",
    "dexie": "^3.2.2",
    "dexie-react-hooks": "^1.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "dripsy": "^4.1.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.8.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "flagsmith": "^3.14.1",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "google-search-results-nodejs": "^2.1.0",
    "graphql": "16.6.0",
    "graphql-rate-limit-directive": "^2.0.2",
    "graphql-scalars": "^1.17.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "html-to-text": "^9.0.5",
    "html5-qrcode": "^2.3.7",
    "image-js": "^0.35.3",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "mailgun.js": "^8.0.1",
    "micro": "^9.3.4",
    "micro-cors": "^0.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.1.0",
    "nanoid": "^3.3.4",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.1.44",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "rc-drawer": "^5.1.0-alpha.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^13.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.6.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^2.7.0",
    "react-google-map-image": "^1.0.3",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.37.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.39.1",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks": "^6.42.0",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks-web": "^6.47.3",
    "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.39.1",
    "react-joyride": "^2.5.3",
    "react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.4",
    "react-lottie-player": "^1.4.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-native": "^0.72.6",
    "react-native-autocomplete-dropdown": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.3.2",
    "react-native-blurhash": "^1.1.10",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.1.8",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.0",
    "react-native-flagsmith": "^3.14.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-snackbar-component": "^1.1.12",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-video-processing": "^1.7.2",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-shepherd": "^4.1.0",
    "react-xarrows": "^2.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "replicate": "^0.16.1",
    "serpapi": "^2.0.0",
    "sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown": "^1.4.0",
    "shepherd.js": "^11.0.1",
    "shippo": "^1.7.1",
    "solito": "^3.2.6",
    "stripe": "^9.9.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
    "timeago-react": "^3.0.5",
    "ts-tiny-invariant": "^2.0.4",
    "turnstone": "^2.2.0",
    "twilio": "^3.81.0",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.0",
    "unique-username-generator": "^1.1.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "victory": "^36.6.11",
    "xstate": "^4.35.2",
    "yet-another-react-lightbox": "^2.2.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zeego": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "resolutions": {
    "bson": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-toolbelt": "9.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-keyboard-event-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "schema-dts": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my next.config.js:

```
// This file sets a custom webpack configuration to use your Next.js app
// with Sentry.
// https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter')
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: false,
})
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments = {
      ...config.experiments,
      topLevelAwait: true,
      layers: true,
    }
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      },
    }
    return config
  },

  transpilePackages: [
    '@emotion/styled',
    'react-native-web',
    'react-native',
    'react-native-linear-gradient',
    'solito',
    'dripsy',
    '@dripsy/core',
    '@expo/match-media',
    'twrnc',
    'app',
    'stripe',
    'sharingan-rn-modal-dropdown',
    'zeego',
    'lottie-react-native',
    '@expo-google-fonts/inter',
    '@gorhom/bottom-sheet',
    '@gorhom/portal',
    '@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native',
    'react-native-reanimated',
    'react-native-screens',
    '@expo/html-elements',
    '@expo/vector-icons',
    'react-native-gesture-handler',
    '@react-native-async-storage',
    'react-native-autocomplete-dropdown',
    'react-native-blurhash',
    'react-native-confirmation-code-field',
    'react-native-country-codes-picker',
    'react-native-easy-grid',
    'react-native-fbsdk-next',
    'react-native-flagsmith',
    'react-native-google-places-autocomplete',
    'react-native-mask-input',
    'react-native-paper',
    'react-native-phone-number-input',
    'react-native-qrcode-svg',
    'react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked',
    'react-native-snackbar-component',
    'react-native-svg',
    'react-native-tab-view',
    'react-native-url-polyfill',
    'react-native-vector-icons',
    '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view',
    'expo-application',
    'expo-auth-session',
    'expo-barcode-scanner',
    'expo-build-properties',
    'expo-cached-image',
    'expo-camera',
    'expo-clipboard',
    'expo-constants',
    'expo-dev-client',
    'expo-font',
    'expo-image',
    'expo-image-picker',
    'expo-linear-gradient',
    'expo-linking',
    'expo-random',
    'expo-screen-orientation',
    'expo-splash-screen',
    'expo-status-bar',
    'expo-web-browser',
    'react-native-ios-context-menu',
    'react-native-pager-view',
    'react-native-safe-area-context',
    'styled-components',
    '@react-native/assets-registry',
    '@expo/next-adapter',
    '@react-native-firebase/auth',
    '@react-native-firebase/app',
    'react-instantsearch-native',
    'react-native-country-picker-modal',
    'expo-modules-core',
    'expo-image-manipulator',
    'expo-asset',
    'expo-crypto',
    '@rneui/base',
    '@react-native',
    '@rneui/themed',
    'react-native-side-drawer',
    'nativewind',
    'expo-file-system',
  ],
  images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    domains: [
      'cdn.chec.io',
      'images.prismic.io',
      'images.ctfassets.net',
      's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
      'res.cloudinary.com',
      'drive.google.com',
      'images.vendoo.co',
      'source.unsplash.com',
      'cdn.shopify.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'api.mapbox.com',
    ],
  },
}

const APP_ENV = process.env.APP_ENV || 'release'

require('dotenv').config({
  path: `../../.env`,
})

const env = {}

Object.keys(process.env).forEach((key) => {
  if (key.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC_')) {
    env[key] = process.env[key]
  }
})

module.exports = //withSentryConfig(
  withPlugins(
    [
      withFonts({
        projectRoot: __dirname,
      }),
      [
        withPWA,
        {
          projectRoot: __dirname,
        },
      ],
      [withExpo], // MAKE SURE THIS GOES LAST!
    ],
    {
      ...nextConfig,
      env,
      // redirects: async () => {
      //   return [
      //     {
      //       source: '/',
      //       destination: 'https://www.biz.karmatrade.com/',
      //       permanent: true,
      //     },
      //   ]
      // },
      async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/@:spaceid',
            destination: '/space/:spaceid',
          },
          {
            source: '/m/@:marketid',
            destination: '/market/:marketid',
          },
        ]
      },
    }
  ) /*,
  { silent: true,  },
  { hideSourceMaps: true }
)*/

/*
withPlugins(
    [
      [withFonts, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
      [withPWA, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
    ],
*/
```

Here is my metro.config.js:

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
/**
 * @type {import('expo/metro-config')}
 */
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config')
const path = require('path')

const projectRoot = __dirname
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..')

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot)

//config.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs')
config.resolver.sourceExts.push('cjs')
config.resolver.sourceExts.push('js')
config.resolver.sourceExts.push('ts')
config.resolver.sourceExts.push('jsx')
config.resolver.sourceExts.push('tsx')

config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot]
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
]

module.exports = config
```

I expected this to be a NextJS/NodeJS/Expo compatability issue. Currently, I am using Expo 49, the latest NextJS and Node 20.8. I've tried downgrading NextJS (13.2, 12.2, 12.1) and Node (16, 18). None of these changed the error.

I also thought this error may be related to Expo not being able to find Node. Inside the .xcode.env.local file, I have guaranteed that the Node path `/opt/homebrew/bin/node` is correct. Changing it causes another error to occur.

I suspect it is something where Expo cannot find Node. Since FS is a module within Node. But I am now at a lost and have been trying to solve this bug for 2 weeks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you’re on next 13.5? Just to be sure, you don’t gitignore your yarn.lock file right?

The error you posted happens if you import Next.js code on native, such as using `next/router somewhere rather than` solito/router`. So I would search your codebase for that. If you do, I would put it in a web-only file using a .web.tsx extension.

The solution:

1. Search `from 'next` in your codebase to find where you're importing code directly from Next.js
2. If it's in many places, you have 2 options:
   a) Change all the imports to be in a web-only file using a `.web.tsx` file (see the solito docs for platform-specific-code.)
   b) If you want to keep importing from `next/router`, you'd need to make that import not do anything on native. One option is to use a babel plugin to strip out the import on native altogether. I'll show you how below.

Option a) mentioned is much better in my opinion. You want to keep certain files out of your native app that could include web-only code.

### Babel Plugin Solution

1. First, install a package:

```bash
cd apps/expo
yarn add -D babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

2. Next, add this file in `apps/expo/next-router-shim.ts`

```
export default {
  push() {},
  replace() {},
  router: null,
}
/**
 * @deprecated You imported from the wrong file!
 */
export const useRouter = () => undefined
```

3. Rewrite `next/router` to your file in your `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)

  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./'],
          alias: {
            'next/router': './next-router-shim',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```

4. Lastly, to prevent VSCode from auto-importing from `next-router-shim`, you can add this file:

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
    "apps/expo/next-router-shim.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The first option worked well! Thank you for the detailed overview